# Oracle UNION ALL preservation of the order of records in query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following scenario(table below) where I would like to pick 'X' or 'Y' based on whether they are NULL or not.

```
  X         Y            pick
  null     not null        Y
  not null not null        X
  not null null            X
```

the rows containing the data 'X' and 'Y' or UNION ALLed like below:

```
  select 'X' as a
  union all
  select 'Y' as a
```

So I tried and got the following SQL but not sure about the "rownum<=1" part. This will  work(for the case where both X and Y are not null) only if UNION ALL preserve 
the order in which I query the two rows.

```
  select a from 
  (
  select 'X' as a
  union all
  select 'Y' as a
  ) where a is not null and rownum<=1;

  select a from 
  (
  select null as a
  union all
  select 'Y' as a
  ) where a is not null and rownum<=1;

  select a from 
  (
  select 'X' as a
  union all
  select null as a
  ) where a is not null and rownum<=1;
```

Is the above right way to go about this?. Any insight would be much appreciated

Comment: The result of a `UNION` or `UNION ALL` is a set. Sets *do not have* an order. Even if you observe an apparent ordering in simple tests, you should not rely on such an order ever being present.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a specific order in SQL, you have to ask for it. You could probably extend your union as:

```
  select a from (
    select a,rownum as rn from 
    (
       select 'X' as a, 0 as Priority from dual
       union all
       select 'Y' as a, 1 as Priority from dual
    ) where a is not null order by Priority
  ) where rn = 1
```

Although I admit I'm not great with Oracle. I believe rownum does odd things in `WHERE` clauses, that's why I've introduced an extra level of querying.

Comment: Two things: 1) you can't issue a `select` without a `from` clause in Oracle. If you're looking to fabricate a row, the standard way to do that is to select from `dual`. 2) I don't see the point of this query: column "a" can't possibly be null and the `rownum` filter will always remove the second half of the union. What's left is the equivalent of `select 'X' as a from dual`.

Comment: @Allan - I was mimicking, as much as possible, the OPs queries. They have 3 identical queries, I've reproduced the first, but added the features I wished to illustrate. I said I wasn't great with Oracle

Answer (score 0):

Coalesce

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions023.htm

Comment: Could you please give an example with coalesce?. I had thought about using coalesce, but it is a function that requires multiple individual values and not multiple records. So I didn't know how to plug it into the query.

Comment: I thought you said at the very beginning that you had a table with two columns, X and Y.  If you don't, please make clearer what you do have.  Coalese takes as arguments two values, usually two column values from the same row.